# Speeding up simulation of the Levy motion algorithm

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

Here is my little script for simulating Levy motion:

```
clear all;
clc; close all;
t = 0; T = 1000; I = T-t;
dT = T/I; t = 0:dT:T; tau = T/I;
alpha = 1.5;
sigma = dT^(1/alpha);
mu = 0; beta = 0;
N = 1000;
X = zeros(N, length(I));
for k=1:N
    L = zeros(1,I);
    for i = 1:I-1
       L( (i + 1) * tau ) = L(i*tau) + stable2( alpha, beta, sigma, mu, 1);
    end
    X(k,1:length(L)) = L;
end

q = 0.1:0.1:0.9;
quant = qlines2(X, q, t(1:length(X)), tau);
hold all
for i = 1:length(quant)
    plot( t, quant(i) * t.^(1/alpha), ':k' );
end
```

Where `stable2` returns a [stable random variable](http://planetmath.org/stablerandomvariable) with given parameters (you may replace it with `normrnd(mu, sigma)` for this case, it's not crucial); `qlines2` returns quantiles needed for plotting.

But I don't want to talk about math here. My problem is that this implementation is pretty slow, and I would like to speed it up. Unfortunately, computer science is not my main field - I heard something about methods like memoization, vectorization and that there is a lot of other techniques, but I don't know how to use them.
For example, I'm pretty sure I should replace this filthy double for-loop somehow, but I'm not sure what to do instead.
EDIT: Maybe I should use (and learn...) another language (Python, C, any functional one)? I always though that Matlab/OCTAVE is designed for numerical computation, but if change, then for which one?

Comment: The script doesn't look too complex, so I'll hazard a guess you will have reasonable performance with an optimized Matlab implementation. Matlab is also pretty forgiving for a newbie - unless best possible performance is an absolute necessity, I feel you should stick with it for now. Especially since you've implemented your simulation there now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial bit is, as you said, the for loops, Matlab does not like those, so *vectorization* is indeed the keyword. (Together with preallocating the space.

I just altered you for loop section somewhat so that you do not have to reset `L` over and over again, instead we save all `L`s in a bigger matrix (also I elimiated the `length(L)` command).

```
L = zeros(N,I);
for k=1:N
    for i = 1:I-1
       L(k,(i + 1) * tau ) = L(k,i*tau) + normrnd(mu, sigma);
    end
    X(k,1:I) = L(k,1:I);
end
```

Now you can already see that `X(k,1:I) = L(k,1:I);` in the loop is obsolete and that also means that we can switch the order of the loops. This is crucial, because the `i`-steps are recursive (depend on the previous step) that means we cannot vectorize this loop, we can only vectorize the `k`-loop.

Now your original code needed 9.3 seconds on my machine, the new code still needs about the same time)

```
L = zeros(N,I);
for i = 1:I-1
    for k=1:N
       L(k,(i + 1) * tau ) = L(k,i*tau) + normrnd(mu, sigma);
    end
end
X = L;
```

But now we can apply the *vectorization*, instead of looping throu all rows (the loop over `k`) we can instead eliminate this loop, and doing all rows at "once".

```
L = zeros(N,I);
for i = 1:I-1
   L(:,(i + 1) * tau ) = L(:,i*tau) + normrnd(mu, sigma); %<- this is not yet what you want, see comment below
end
X = L;
```

This code need only 0.045 seconds on my machine. I hope you still get the same output, because I have no idea what you are calculating, but I also hope you could see how you go about vectorizing code.

**PS:** I just noticed that we now use the same random number in the last example for the whole column, this is obviously not what you want. Instad you should generate a whole vector of random numbers, e.g:

```
L = zeros(N,I);
for i = 1:I-1
   L(:,(i + 1) * tau ) = L(:,i*tau) + normrnd(mu, sigma,N,1);
end
X = L;
```

PPS: Great question!

Comment: Nice work. I believe for the simulation it is necessary to draw multiple samples with `normrnd` rather than one. This is achieved with the syntax `normrnd(mu, sigma, M, N, ...)` where `M`, `N` etc. are the desired dimensions of the output array. And the [usual caveats of using `i` or `j` as loop variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) apply.

Comment: @mikkola Thank you for letting me know, I just noticed this too and added a paragraph.

Comment: It works glorious, thank you! And yes, correction (your PS) was needed, since I wanted matrix of simulated paths.

Comment: @PhotonLight And another thing, this code now works only because `tau` is exactly 1.

Comment: Yes, I see, that's another issue, but for now I can assume it's true - in reality it represents time step, for simple cases it can be 1. I will talk with my prof. if it can be solved, maybe another implementation is needed, but now I know more about optimization, so should be easier!